# Unable to create a folder inside a blob container using azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

New to ADF so pardon me if this is pretty basic.

Trying to copy bla.docx from source(blob container)/screenshots(folder)/bla.docx to target(blob container)/screenshots(folder).

But screenshots folder doesn't exist in target container. Need to make it using the pipeline.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create 2 datasets for source and sink individually. It's ok that you have no target directory in the sink dataset. You just need to define it in the sink dataset configuration and ADF will create it for you.

[image]

Test output:

[image]